# Unable to pass values through didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table view. When a tableview cell is clicked, im grabbing a specific textlabel value. In APIRequest.m file I have a variable `shipmentReferenceNo` whose value im assigning as textlabel value on didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:123123];
    self.request = [[APIRequest alloc]init];

    self.request.shipmentReferenceNo = label.text;

    NSLog(@"hello %@",  label.text);

}
```

When im trying to access the  shipmentReferenceNo as follows from APIRequest.m file as follows, its null

```
NSLog(@"sd %@",self.shipmentReferenceNo);
```

what could be possible reason for this null value though i have assigned it previously in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: it is because you are creating a new instance again. self.request = [[APIRequest alloc]init]; You just remove it.As you already declared self.request as a property!Also you need to look for self.request.shipmentReferenceNo and not self.shipmentReferenceNo

Comment: i tried it but still im having the same problem

Comment: put a breakpoint in didSelect method and try to print the value of self.request in the debugger.

Comment: NSLog(@"hello %@",  label.text); is null, if i remove self.request.shipmentReferenceNo

Comment: don't use viewWithTag. Subclass the tablecell and declare the label properties, and use them wherever needed.

Comment: @user1241241 did you assign tag to label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
 {
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:123];
   self.request = [[APIRequest alloc]init];
   self.request.shipmentReferenceNo = label.text;
   NSLog(@"hello %@",  label.text);

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
 });
```

}

also inside table view data source :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = ;
  [cell.label setTag:123];
}
```

This will work but I will suggest to make your code more organise by moving the dispatch_async code to separate method.